# Fold over a heterogeneous, compile time, list

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, hlist

I have a list of heterogeneous types (or at least that's what I have in mind):

```
data Nul

data Bits b otherBits where 
    BitsLst :: b -> otherBits -> Bits b otherBits 
    NoMoreBits :: Bits b Nul
```

Now, given an input type `b`, I want to go through all the slabs of `Bits` with type `b` and summarize them, ignoring other slabs with type `b' /= b`:

```
class Monoid r => EncodeBit b r | b -> r where 
    encodeBit :: b -> r

class AbstractFoldable aMulti r where 
    manyFold :: r -> aMulti -> r

instance (EncodeBit b r, AbstractFoldable otherBits r) => 
                     AbstractFoldable (Bits b otherBits ) r where 
    manyFold r0 (BitsLst bi other) = manyFold (r0 `mappend` (encodeBit bi)) other
    manyFold b0 NoMoreBits = b0 

instance AbstractFoldable otherBits r =>
                     AbstractFoldable (Bits nb    otherBits ) r where 
    manyFold r0 (BitsLst _ other) = manyFold r0 other
    manyFold b0 NoMoreBits = b0
```

But the compiler wants none of it. And with good reason, since both instance declarations have the same head. Question: what is the correct way of folding over `Bits` with an arbitrary type?

Note: the above example is compiled with

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, 
             FunctionalDependencies,
             GADTs,
             DataKinds,
             FlexibleInstances,
             FlexibleContexts
#-}
```

Comment: It seems that you want to fold over only those elements of the list which are instances of `EncodeBit`. Why do you want to do that? (Also, it's impossible. Haskell doesn't have "not instance of class" constraints). Instead, you could require that all types are `EncodeBit`, and then fold over all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your comment:

> Actually, I can do if I can filter the heterogeneous list by type. Is that possible?

You can filter the heterogeneous list by type if you add a `Typeable` constraint to `b`.

The main idea is we will use `Data.Typeable`'s [`cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) to determine if each item in the list is of a certain type. This will require a `Typeable` constraint for each item in the list. Instead of building a new list type with this constraint built in, we will make the ability to check if `All` types in a list meet some constraint.

Our goal is to make the following program output `[True,False]`, filtering a heterogeneous list to only its `Bool` elements. I will endevour to place the language extensions and imports with the first snippet they are needed for

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

example :: HList (Bool ': String ': Bool ': String ': '[])
example = HCons True $ HCons "Jack" $ HCons False $ HCons "Jill" $ HNil

main = do
    print (ofType example :: [Bool])
```

`HList` here is a fairly standard definition of a heterogeneous list in haskell using `DataKinds`

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data HList (l :: [*]) where
    HCons :: h -> HList t -> HList (h ': t)
    HNil :: HList '[]
```

We want to write `ofType` with a signature like "if `All` things in a heterogeneous list are `Typeable`, get a list of those things of a specific `Typeable` type.

```
import Data.Typeable

ofType :: (All Typeable l, Typeable a) => HList l -> [a]
```

To do this, we need to develop the notion of `All` things in a list of types satisfying some constraint. We will store the dictionaries for satisfied constraints in a `GADT` that either captures both the head constraint  dictionary and constraints for `All` of the the tail or proves that the list is empty. A type list satisfies a constraint for `All` it's items if we can capture the dictionaries for it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

-- requires the constraints† package.
-- Constraint is actually in GHC.Prim
-- it's just easier to get to this way
import Data.Constraint (Constraint)

class All (c :: * -> Constraint) (l :: [*]) where
    allDict :: p1 c -> p2 l -> DList c l

data DList (ctx :: * -> Constraint) (l :: [*]) where
    DCons :: (ctx h, All ctx t) => DList ctx (h ': t)
    DNil  ::                       DList ctx '[]
```

`DList` really is a list of dictionaries. `DCons` captures the dictionary for the constraint applied to the head item (`ctx h`) and all the dictionaries for the remainder of the list (`All ctx t`). We can't get the dictionaries for the tail directly from the constructor, but we can write a function that extracts them from the dictionary for `All ctx t`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Proxy

dtail :: forall ctx h t. DList ctx (h ': t) -> DList ctx t
dtail DCons = allDict (Proxy :: Proxy ctx) (Proxy :: Proxy t)
```

An empty list of types trivially satisfies any constraint applied to all of its items

```
instance All c '[] where
    allDict _ _ = DNil
```

If the head of a list satisfies a constraint and all of the tail does too, then everything in the list satisfies the constraint.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (c h, All c t) => All c (h ': t) where
    allDict _ _ = DCons
```

We can now write `ofType`, which requires `forall`s for scoping type variables with `ScopedTypeVariables`.

```
import Data.Maybe

ofType :: forall a l. (All Typeable l, Typeable a) => HList l -> [a]
ofType l = ofType' (allDict (Proxy :: Proxy Typeable) l) l
  where
    ofType' :: forall l. (All Typeable l) => DList Typeable l -> HList l -> [a]
    ofType' d@DCons (HCons x t) = maybeToList (cast x) ++ ofType' (dtail d) t
    ofType' DNil    HNil        = []
```

We are zipping the `HList` together with its dictionaries with `maybeToList . cast` and concatenating the results. We can make that explicit with `RankNTypes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Monoid (Monoid, (<>), mempty)

zipDHWith :: forall c w l p. (All c l, Monoid w) => (forall a. (c a) => a -> w) -> p c -> HList l -> w
zipDHWith f p l = zipDHWith' (allDict p l) l
  where
    zipDHWith' :: forall l. (All c l) => DList c l -> HList l -> w
    zipDHWith' d@DCons (HCons x t) = f x <> zipDHWith' (dtail d) t
    zipDHWith' DNil    HNil        = mempty

ofType :: (All Typeable l, Typeable a) => HList l -> [a]
ofType = zipDHWith (maybeToList . cast) (Proxy :: Proxy Typeable)
```

---

†[constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints)

Comment: This is really cool! I'm slowly reading and assimilating now. Thanks a lot!